# Wrapping HTML inside a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to inject some html markup inside my html page with jQuery.

**I need to** surround highlighted yellow code below with `<div class="section">`...`</div>`.

So I need something like this:

```
<div class="section">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

For that I use the id (highlighted in green) and `parent` and `before` or `append` method.

**The problem:** when using `before` or `append` methods, jQuery always self close my tags so I end up with `<div class="section"></div>`...

[image]

Any idea how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: That is the default behavior of these methods. You cannot append html in bits. The end tags are automatically handled.

Comment: Unfair downvote by my count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.nextUntil()` to target the divs in between and wrap the section using `.wrapAll()`

```js
$('div[id^=320]').nextUntil("div[id^=760]").add("div[id^=320], div[id^=760]").wrapAll('<div class="section"></div>');
```

```css
.section {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div id="320">...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div id="760">...</div>
<div>...</div>
```

Comment: The problem here is that you encapsulate all divs but in my case I need only a few of it... As you can see on my screenshot before and after the highlighted yellow code I have other divs.

Comment: You can use CSS pseudo selectors to target specific element. Which one do you need?

Comment: I need successive divs beginning at the div with id="721..." and ending at the div with the id="569...". (and so all divs between).

Comment: I have edited the answer. You can use that for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.wcustomhtml').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().wrap('<div class="section"></div>');
})
```

I am not sure if only the highlighted elements have this class, if not, you need to give them some class to identify them and then each() them and wrap() their parent.

hope this helps